# How to select elements in a specific order with XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I have a XML file with nodes (Z) containing child nodes (H, W, P) in a random order:

```
<X>
  <Y>
    <Z>
      <H>Hello</H>
      <W>World</W>
      <P>!</P>
    </Z>
    <Z>
      <P>!</P>
      <W>World</W>
      <H>Hello</H>
    </Z>
  </Y>
</X>
```

And I would like to select the content of the child nodes in a given order.

I tied this:

```
/X/Y/Z/*[self::H or self::W or self::P]/text()
```

But this will keep the wrong order:

```
Hello World !
! World Hello
```

I need some way to select the W and P relative to H in a sequence. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
/X/Y/Z/(H,W,P)/text()
```

But the order is still wrong.

**Edit:** The questions suggests that I need only the text portion, but I need the node and not only the text. The reason is, that the XPath text() function seems to have a problem with CDATA sections.

Comment: @JWiley: That expression is valid XPath 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XPath 2:

Using the / to select nodes will always return the nodes in document order, no matter how you write it.

If you, however, select atomic values instead of nodes it will keep the order:

```
/X/Y/Z/concat(H,W,P)
```

You can also use for-in-return which will never change the order:

```
for $z in /X/Y/Z return ($z/H,$z/W,$z/P)
```

For XPath 3:

In a real modern implementation you can also use ! instead of / which will also always keep the order, and is otherwise  the same as /   (and it will also keep duplicates):

```
 /X/Y/Z ! (H,W,P) ! text()
```

Comment: It seems to me that `concat` works only with strings but not with nodes.

Comment: All functions should work with nodes. If a node is passed to a function expecting a non-node, it is "atomized" by calling data which usually converts it to a type xs:untypedAtomic. so `concat($z/H, $z/W)` is equivalent to `concat( data($z/H), data($z/W))`

Comment: Java's (7) default XPath implementation of concat returns a string and not a nodelist. The for syntax is not supported either. And I think XPath 3 also not. ;-)

Comment: well it  always *returns* a string. But the *input* can be a node.  @ edit: cdata sections are handled by converting them to their (string) value

Comment: When I use this `/root/text()` xpath on this file `<root>Hello <![CDATA[World]]>!</root>` I get this result: `Hello `. Is it a bug of the xpath engine?

Comment: No, xpath is reading `<![CDATA[World]]>` as a child node of `<root>`, so if you're accessing /root/text() as a node you'll only get the first part "Hello". Try just /root

Comment: But xmllint behaves differently. This `xmllint --nocdata --xpath '/root/text()'` returns this `Hello World!`. Maybe there is a bug how I use the XPath API.

Comment: /root/text() is the 3-element sequence (Hello , World, !) . xmllint probably prints it all to stdout, so it appears at a sentence. In the way you are accessing it, you might only get the first element

Comment: @BeniBela Java does not return a three element sequence for `/root/text()`. Instead [evaluate(doc,NODESET)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathExpression.html#evaluate%28org.xml.sax.InputSource,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) returns a node list with one element containing only `Hello ` with the trailing space. This `/root/descendant::text()` does not help either.

Comment: @BeniBela Java XPath seems to be buggy here, because of that I can not use the `text()` function. Instead I need a node list. But a node list can not be created with `concat`. Looks like a dead lock.

Answer (score 0):

XPath will always go by the structure of the XML document tree itself, so the XPath `[self::H or self::W or self::P]/text()` will always return the H, W, and P nodes in the order in which they appear, which is why you see "Hello World !" and "! World Hello".

Since you only want the text here, you could use concatenate function like so:

`concat(/X/Y/Z/H, /X/Y/Z/W, /X/Y/Z/P)`